# why is the restcomm example not working over mobile data connection?

Tags: android, restcomm

I want to use restcomm android example over mobile data connection. ..its working over wifi connection but not on mobile connection what could be the cause?

Comment: Which example are you referring to? One of the sample applications that ships with the RestComm Android SDK at https://github.com/Mobicents/restcomm-android-sdk?

Comment: yes I'm referring to those examples

Comment: Ok, so we had some issues during testing the mobile data connection and we have disabled it until we properly support TURN which will solve these issues. Reason is that mobile operators are more strict and as a result the STUN pings associated in reflexive candidates fail in one direction.

Comment: so when would this be sorted ....? I really like using restcom

Comment: It's due for next release i.e. 1.0.0 BETA4 (please check https://github.com/RestComm/restcomm-android-sdk/milestones for scheduling). By the way would you be interested to contribute a fix for that in the Restcomm Android SDK? Shouldn't be too much work ;)